If a graded ring $S$ is a UFD, then $S_0$ is a UFD
Let $S$ be a commutative graded ring ($S = \oplus_{n \in Z} S_n$). If $S$ is a UFD, can we deduce $S_0$ is a UFD?
I think $S_0$ is a UFD. Because we can gather all the finite product of the irreducible elements in $S_0$, that is
$$
\{p_{1} p_{2} \dots p_m \in S_0 | p_1, \dots, p_m \mbox{ are irreducible in } S\},
$$
Then $S_0$ has enough irreducible elements to represent all the elements as products of $S_0$.
The problem comes from Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry (II, 6.17), where we need to verify the degree-$0$ ring of every  localization of $k[x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n]$ is a UFD.

I would maybe choose to go contrapositive here.

That's not the contrapositive, that's the converse. The contrapositive is "$S_0$ not UFD $\implies$ $S$ not UFD". Contrapositives are equivalent. And unless I have overlooked some subtlety, this contrapositive variant is easier to prove than the direct variant.

Gather all the finite product of the irreducible elements in $S_0$, that is
$$
\{p_{1} p_{2} \dots p_m \in S_0 | p_1, \dots, p_m \mbox{ are irreducible in } S  \},
$$
Then $S_0$ has enough irreducible elements to represent all the elements as products of $S_0$.
